# differential equation/Lipschitz.

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Show that $\sqrt{1 + f^2} \in Lip([a, b])$, $\forall f \in Lip([a, b])$.

I have an exam tommorrow and i can't wrap my head around this problem.
So I was thinking to start with the definiton:
$|f(x) - f(y)| \le L|x-y|$ , but doesn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By continuity $\exists M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for every $x \in [a,b]$
$$|1 + f(x)^2 - (1 + f(y)^2 )| =  |f(x)^2 - f(y)^2| = |(f(x) - f(y))(f(x) + f(y))| \leq 2ML|x - y|$$
so $1 + f^2 \in Lip([a,b])$. The square root is Lipschitz on any compact subinterval of $(0,+\infty)$, since the image of $1 + f^2$ is a compact subinterval of $(0,+\infty)$ we have:
$$\Big|\sqrt{1 + f(x)^2} - \sqrt{1 + f(y)^2}\Big| \leq K |1 + f(x)^2 - (1 + f(y)^2 )| \leq 2KML|x - y|$$
Here $K$ is the Lipschitz constant of the square root on the image of $1 + f^2$

Comment: I succeeded just the first part of the exercise,  but I wouldn't  finish the exercise without you. Thank you!

Comment: @antonio You are welcome:) it is a general fact that the composition of two Lipschitz functions is again a Lipschitz function